# É possivel fazer uma requisição http a um domínio externo por XMLHttpRequest em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-service, xmlhttprequest

Eu estou trabalhando no meu TCC e nele planejei fazer um *web service* com PHP. Ele está hospedado em um *host* externo enquanto a página web está no meu localhost/servido do Cotil-Unicamp, até que está andando, mas agora me deparei com isso, o `XMLHttpRequest` pelo jeito não me permite fazer uma requisição para outro domínio por conta da política de mesma origem.

Então eu gostaria de saber se existe algo que eu tenho que fazer para que o `XMLHttpRequest` permita a requisição ou alguma outra maneira de fazer requisições de forma que possa acessar domínios externos.

Sim, já pesquisei no Google, talvez não tenha feito isso direito já que é minha primeira vez desenvolvendo algo como *web service* e não tenho tanta noção dos termos técnicos, então me desculpem pela falta de experiência.

Eu vi algo do tipo usar `iframes` escondidos no HTML, mas achei meio que gambiarra isso então descartei.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa permitir a origem do request, no php vc poderia fazer algo como:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
....
?>
```

Você poderia também permitir uma origem especifica trocando o * pelo domínio. Como é local host o * é a melhor saída creio eu.

Caso você tenha controle do webserver onde o php está, pode definir este cabeçalho no próprio webserver:

Apache:

https://tecadmin.net/set-access-control-allow-origin-cors-in-apache/

NGINX

https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx

Comment: Então eu já tinha feito isso, mas o javascript continua me mostrando o mesmo warning de política de mesma origem, então eu achei que o problema era com o script, eu realmente não sei o que esta errado

Comment: Todas as vezes que eu esbarrei em algum problema de cors a solução foi liberar no servidor.. vc pode tentar alcançar o seu php via postman ou no proprio painel de rede do navegador verificar se o cabeçalho está vindo. Outra tentativa, caso não esteja usando um webserver local (Acessando diretamente o arquivo com file://) é implementar um webserver local e testar...

Comment: Agora entendi, depois de você ter falado sobre liberar no host fui pesquisar, e realmente o infinity free, não suporta esse recurso, eu realmente não sabia que tinha toda essa problema por parte do servidor, erro meu desculpa ocupar o seu tempo, mas foi como eu disse não tenho experiência com isso ainda, e por acaso você conhece algum host que me permita fazer isso, que seja de graça? afinal é só um TCC, de qualquer forma obrigado!

Comment: @Lds20k, relaxa, estamos aqui pra ajudar. Sobre o host nenhum me vem a cabeça... Você poderia tentar o free-tier da Amazon ou Azure para tentar resolver... O lado ruim é que em ambos você precisará configurar o server. Não seria viável você hospedar o seu JS no mesmo host ou rodar seu programa PHP localmente também?

Comment: Sim, eu vi o que você tinha falado ali em cima, eu tinha pensado nessa opção do js no mesmo host, mas ao meu ver iria fugir do conceito de web service e iria virar uma sopa de js e php, desculpa pela minha mania de organização... E a respeito de fazer local, eu tinha começado a desenvolver ele local mesmo, mas o problema é que eu não estou fazendo sozinho o TCC, tenho mais 3 companheiros comigo, cada um desenvolvendo um front diferente, por essa questão que achei mais razoável utilizar na web, vou dar umas olhadas nessas opções que você passou, valeu!